# Getting a EmailMessage Attachment via FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have this code here where I retrieve an attachment from an Email Message that is on the Exchange Server using EWS

```
            Attachment attachment = message.Attachments.Single(att => att.ContentId == Request.QueryString["cid"]);
            attachment.Load();
            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;


            fileAttachment.Load();
            byte[] bytes = fileAttachment.Content;
            Stream theMemStream = new MemoryStream();

            theMemStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            return new FileStreamResult( theMemStream, attachment.ContentType);
```

I can download the file just fine however they are corrupted... Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.filecontents.aspx) directly instead - that way you don't have to go via a `MemoryStream`. That way, you have less risk of breaking anything.

```
return FileContent(fileAttachment.Content, attachment.ContentType);
```

You might also want to set the `FileDownloadName` if you *don't* want the file to display inline within the browser.

Comment: apparently i forgot to theMemStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); that's why so your right... thanks...

Comment: @Sevki That's a classic. I missed it too. :)